# Changing css file in a web application

Tags: html, css, forms, razor

I have a web aplication , in which i have to specify a new css file to this section :

```
<section id="loginForm" >
<h2>Connecter à notre application</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Formulaire de connexion</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("Name")
                @Html.TextBox("Name")

            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.Label("Password")
                @Html.Password("Password")

            </li>

        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Se connecter" />
    </fieldset>

}
</section>
```

For example , the hole View is associated with the css file `X` and i'd like to associate another `Y` css file only for this section.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scoped CSS is coming, but the support isn't very good yet. Read more here: http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/ and http://html5doctor.com/the-scoped-attribute/#link

In the meantime, an alternative is to prefix all your selectors in your `Y` css file with `#loginForm`. With a preprocessor like SASS or LESS, this is very easy (wrap the file contents once), but becomes very tedious in plain CSS.